# Spring JPA + postgres - how do you store a createdOn field?

Tags: java, spring, postgresql, jpa

I am trying to create my model for `User` as follows, but I am having trouble with `createdOn`.  I've created a column in my postgres db table of data type `Date` called `createdOn`.

How can I have the date reflect the create user date?

Here is snippet of my User class:

```
@Entity
@Table(name="users")
public class User {

    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.AUTO)
    @Column(name="userid")
    private long userid;

    @NotNull
    @Column(name="username")
    private String username;

    @NotNull
    @Column(name="email")
    private String email;

    @NotNull
    @Column(name="firstname")
    private String firstname;

    @NotNull
    @Column(name="lastname")
    private String lastname;

    @Column(name="createdOn")
    private Date createdOn;

    public User() {
    }

    // getters and setters
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to specify the kind of Date object you want to store in order to do that you can use `@Temporal(TemporalType.TIMESTAMP)`

[Here](http://javabeat.net/jpa-annotations-temporal/) you have a few examples of how to use this tag.

In order to reflect the creation date, you can add a default value with a column definition and a default sysdate.

[postgresql default values](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/9.3/static/ddl-default.html)